# Automatically record a changing cell value to a separate sheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, recording

I have a cell containing Profit/Loss that changes as I make changes to the sheet and I want the value of this cell to be recorded in Sheet2 in column A automatically each day so I have a list of past values. I'm really new to this and I've heard of macros but I don't know how to use them so if anyone has some code for this could you talk me through the steps of exactly what to do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: SuperUser is not a code for me, teach me to code, or Show me where to start site.

Comment: I'd recommend searching for "excel change tracking" or something like that, both on SU and Google. Try some things out. If you get stuck, let us know what you're trying and what is giving you a hard time. Without more information, examples of your sheets, or steps you've already taken, it's hard to help.